# Apache does not redirect to index.php

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

I have a very simple httpd 2.4 configuration on AWS AMI 2 running on EC2.
My application is in /var/www/html/ with an index.php

Reaching **ec2-domain.amazonaws.com/** serves index.php without any issue. So does **ec2-domain.amazonaws.com/index.php**
However, **ec2-domain.amazonaws.com/endpoint** returns 404, whereas **ec2-domain.amazonaws.com/index.php/endpoint** serves the expect page.

My httpd config is extremely basic.
All files in /var/www/html/ are owned by apache:apache.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: By my understanding, I think you want to get index.php to be displayed in endpoint page.

Answer (score 0):

Under `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf`

Change DirectoryIndex from index.html to index.php

Comment: I'm using httpd so /etc/httpd.conf is relevant here.
I changed that already
`<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>`

Comment: HTTPD is not different from Apache. Actually, Apache is also called Apache HTTPD, which means Apache HTTP Daemon.